# Registration Error php, mysql, no data in database

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I've been stuck for a couple days connecting the registration looking through forums etc. No error seems to populate on the page, but when I take a look at phpMyAdmin it doesn't show the registration info inserted in the db.

**register.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")

{

    header("Location: home.php");

}
$servername = "correctly inserted info";
$username = "correctly inserted info";
$password = "correctly inserted info";
$dbname = "correctly inserted info";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);



if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))

{
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);

$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));


 if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fullname,username,email,password)  VALUES('$fname','$uname','$email','$upass')"))


{

    ?>

    <script>alert('successfully registered');</script>

    <?php

}

else

{

    ?>

    <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>

    <?php

}

}

?>
```

**registration.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="description" content="Violate Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Super Admin, Admin, Template, Bootstrap">

    <title>Super Admin Responsive Template</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/generics.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 </head>
  <body id="skin-blur-violate">
    <section id="login">
        <header>
            <h1>SUPER ADMIN</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Nulla eu risus. Curabitur commodo lorem fringilla enim feugiat commodo sed ac lacus.</p>
        </header>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

       <!-- Login -->
        <form class="box tile animated active" id="box-login">

        <!-- Register -->
        <?php require_once("register.php"); ?>

        <form class="box animated tile" id="box-register" method="post">

            <h2 class="m-t-0 m-b-15">Register</h2>
            <input type="text" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Full Name" name="fname" required/>
            <input type="text" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Username" name="uname" required/>
            <input type="email" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" required/>    
            <input type="password" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Password" name="pass" required/>

            <button class="btn btn-sm m-r-5" type="submit">Register</button>

            <small><a class="box-switcher" data-switch="box-login"  href="">Already have an Account?</a></small>
        </form>

        <!-- Forgot Password -->

    </section>                      

    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Library -->

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--  Form Related -->
        <script src="js/icheck.js"></script> <!-- Custom Checkbox +  Radio -    ->

        <!-- All JS functions -->
        <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've editing the code to help cause I'm still coming up with the same issue, but many seem to be on the right track.  I was using mysql and mysqli interchangeably.  I looking in my dbconnect.php file and found the following which looks like I'll also need to change to make it uniform with the mysqli being displayed in other areas.  On the right track, but not there yet.

I just found though that dbconnect.php is deploying the mysql version and not the mysql version any thoughts?

I just found though that dbconnect.php is deploying the mysql version and not the mysql version any thoughts?

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php

if(!mysql_connect("correct host","correct username","correct password"))

{

die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());

}

if(!mysql_select_db("correct db"))

{

die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysql_error());

}



?>
```

Based on the starting responses I found that many we're helping me get on the right track...here are the other correlating files since the general theme is I am interchanging mysql and mysqli.  Parts of it seemed to work initially but now it's all coming apart so if anyone can help me put it all back together again appreciate it.  I'm still having no response from posting to the database which is why I'm making the edits.

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once 'dbconnect.php';



if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")

{

header("Location: home.php");

}



if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))

{

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);



if($row['password']==md5($upass))

{

    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];

    header("Location: home.php");

}

else

{

    ?>

    <script>alert('wrong details');</script>

    <?php

}



}

?>
```

Just so I'm showing all I have in this process....I'm also putting in my login.php file so hopefully I can get this all resolved.

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-    scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="description" content="Violate Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Super Admin, Admin, Template, Bootstrap">

    <title>Super Admin Responsive Template</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/generics.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body id="skin-blur-violate">
    <section id="login">
        <header>
            <h1>SUPER ADMIN</h1> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu risus. Curabitur commodo lorem fringilla enim feugiat commodo sed ac lacus.</p>
        </header>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- Login -->
        <?php require_once("index.php"); ?>

 <form class="box tile animated active" id="box-login">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 m-b-15">Login</h2>
            <input type="text" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Username or Email Address">
            <input type="password" class="login-control" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="checkbox m-b-20">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="btn-login" class="btn btn-sm m-r-5">Sign In</button>

            <small>
                <a href="registration.php">Don't have an Account?</a> or
                <a class="box-switcher" data-switch="box-reset" href="">Forgot Password?</a>
            </small>
        </form>

        <!-- Forgot Password -->
        <form class="box animated tile" id="box-reset">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 m-b-15">Reset Password</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu risus. Curabitur commodo lorem fringilla enim feugiat commodo sed ac lacus.</p>
            <input type="email" class="login-control m-b-20" placeholder="Email Address">    

            <button class="btn btn-sm m-r-5">Reset Password</button>

            <small><a class="box-switcher" data-switch="box-login" href="">Already have an Account?</a></small>
        </form>
    </section>                      

    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Library -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Form Related -->
    <script src="js/icheck.js"></script> <!-- Custom Checkbox + Radio -->

    <!-- All JS functions -->
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing up `mysql` and `mysqli`

Comment: and this is failing you for 2 reasons `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` - plus, this piece of code is very familiar. You've taken this from the same place as previously posted questions.

Comment: and your POST arrays are failing, something that all answers given so far, have not picked up on. Your code is literally stitched with syntax errors. Oh and `if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))` that will NEVER happen.

Comment: Note to all answerers so far: Your answers will all fail. Double check it, you missed quite a few things. If you receive downvotes, they would NOT have come from me.

Comment: I found something else along the same lines....in the dbconnect.php file I also have the same mysql adjustments....I have the following:

Comment: added more to present more of my findings in the other areas.  I'm trying to find a good connection to connect myadmin panel to a full register, and login....I'd be open to using a different code just having problem finding something that I can connect into the html/php/bootstrap of the admin signin I already have.

Answer (score 2):

**Errors**

1. You are **conflicting `mysql` and `mysqli`**.
2. **`name` attribute is not define** on here `<button class="btn btn-sm m-r-5" type="submit">Register</button>`
3. In *register.php* you check **`isset` with an class**, **This will never works** `if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))`
4. As well as your **Form `name` field and retrieve fields are wrong**.(form - `placeholder="Full Name" name="fname"`/ in code - `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname'])`)

---

**Improvements**

> To check variable is null or empty use `empty()` keyword

Change this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")

{

    header("Location: home.php");

}
```

to this

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

---

**Bug Fixed code**

**In `register.php`**

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $upass = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass']));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fullname,username,email,password)  VALUES('$fname','$uname','$email','$upass')";
     if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('successfully registered');
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else{
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('error while registering you...');
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}
```

**In `registration.php`**

```
<button class="btn btn-sm m-r-5" type="submit" name="register">Register</button>
```

Comment: double check that and see my comments under their question

Comment: @Fred-ii- I Didnt get you

Comment: look over their form and POST arrays

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanx. got the error

Comment: You're welcome. Seems ok, but you really should outline the OP's errors and for future readers to the question/answer ;-) Otherwise, some may not know what you did in order to "fix" their code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Your tips and tricks are more important to me. Thanx a lot. i have mentioned errors on top. is it enough or any thing to be done ??

Comment: Looks good to me Abdulla ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. Grate Man to follow. (y)

Comment: You're welcome Abdulla, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you were mixing both `mysql` and `mysqli` extensions.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    if( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) && !empty( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) header("location: home.php");


    $servername = "correctly inserted info";
    $username = "correctly inserted info";
    $password = "correctly inserted info";
    $dbname = "correctly inserted info";
    $conn = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );


    /* Could not see a form element with that name: $_POST['btn-signup'] */

    if( isset( $_POST['fullname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] ) ) {
        $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['fullname'] );
        $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['username'] );
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['email'] );
        $upass = md5( mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['password'] ) );

        /* Had ommitted the connection object */
        if( mysqli_query( $conn, "INSERT INTO `users` ( `fullname`, `username`, `email`, `password` ) VALUES ( '$fname', '$uname', '$email', '$upass' )" ) ) {
            echo "<script>alert('successfully registered');</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: double check that and see my comments under their question

Comment: I adjusted and still don't seem to have any change...the screen flickers when clicking register, but nothing appears in the database...I'm sure the server name, username, password, and dbname are all correct.

Answer (score -1):

$conn = new **mysqli**($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$fname = **mysql**_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);

check them

them also try using some error reporting at the very top of the php code block ..

Comment: double check that and see my comments under their question