# Bootstrap admin panel connection to user/login issues

Tags: php, mysql, templates, mysqli, user-registration

I just posted an issue I was having with trying to add in all different types of sql to connect the template for "https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/super-admin-responsive-frontend-WB02N9M12" to the login/registration.  I even blogged with the original maker of the code to find out what they recommend using to connect.  The problem I'm having is that the template has the following in the login.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="description" content="Violate Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Super Admin, Admin, Template, Bootstrap">

    <title>Super Admin Responsive Template</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/generics.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body id="skin-blur-violate">
    <section id="login">
        <header>
            <h1>SUPER ADMIN</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu risus. Curabitur commodo lorem fringilla enim feugiat commodo sed ac lacus.</p>
        </header>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <!-- Login -->
        <form class="box tile animated active" id="box-login">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 m-b-15">Login</h2>
            <input type="text" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Username or Email Address">
            <input type="password" class="login-control" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="checkbox m-b-20">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    Remember Me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-sm m-r-5">Sign In</button>

            <small>
                <a class="box-switcher" data-switch="box-register" href="">Don't have an Account?</a> or
                <a class="box-switcher" data-switch="box-reset" href="">Forgot Password?</a>
            </small>
        </form>

        <!-- Register -->
        <form class="box animated tile" id="box-register">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 m-b-15">Register</h2>
            <input type="text" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Full Name">
            <input type="text" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="email" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Email Address">    
            <input type="password" class="login-control m-b-10" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="password" class="login-control m-b-20" placeholder="Confirm Password">

            <button class="btn btn-sm m-r-5">Register</button>

            <small><a class="box-switcher" data-switch="box-login" href="">Already have an Account?</a></small>
        </form>

        <!-- Forgot Password -->
        <form class="box animated tile" id="box-reset">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 m-b-15">Reset Password</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eu risus. Curabitur commodo lorem fringilla enim feugiat commodo sed ac lacus.</p>
            <input type="email" class="login-control m-b-20" placeholder="Email Address">    

            <button class="btn btn-sm m-r-5">Reset Password</button>

            <small><a class="box-switcher" data-switch="box-login"    href="">Already have an Account?</a></small>
        </form>
    </section>                      

    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Library -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Form Related -->
    <script src="js/icheck.js"></script> <!-- Custom Checkbox + Radio -->

    <!-- All JS functions -->
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

Every example I'm given has a register.php or login.php page that references the html for it's own login, and some even switch between mysql and mysqli in other connectors like the dbconnect.php pages.  I don't mean to ramble just been a headache for a week straight now.  Does anyone have any help to get this template connected properly.  I even went so far as to use  in line for the registration and the same for login to reference a connection page to the db.  It works somewhat, but I got to the point where I fill out the registration and it won't display in the referenced table in the mysql database I have setup.  All connections work...just don't have the code that posts it properly.  Thank you anyone got help...I don't know how many more code pieces that run me int he wrong direction I can read through.  The only other post I have here is the code that I was using to try and separate the login to work, but to no avail.

This is where I put the code on stack overflow where I tried to get things corrected.  But nothing seemed to work so I thought I'd reference if anyone else had any guidance even if I need to start the code over.  [Registration Error php, mysql, no data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33463482/5512763)